# print $PATH line by line

Tags: shell, sed, path

The usual code to check the $PATH variable `echo $PATH` often print out some long and cumbersome line like:
`/anaconda2/bin:/anaconda2/condabin:/usr/local/Cellar/root/6.16.00/bin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin`
which has bad readability. Is there any way I can print all the paths line by line instead on a single line? Like this:

```
/anaconda2/bin
/anaconda2/condabin
/usr/local/Cellar/root/6.16.00/bin
~/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/TeX/texbin
/opt/X11/bin
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using `tr`:

```
echo $PATH | tr : '\n'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}
```

use *variable substitution* to replace the colon with a newline

> ${var//Pattern/Replacement}

> -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
>
> If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:
>
> \\     backslash

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'
```

sed is a stream editor, and what it does here is searching for every instance of character ':' and replace it with a \newline character. 'g' is a flag indicating that the find & replace is global (the default is to replace one instance per line).

You can also wrap the code around a function in bash profile:

```
function printpath() {
  echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'
}
```

so you can just type `printpath` to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use one of the following `awk` approach:

```
echo $PATH | awk -F':' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'
```

**output:**

```
/usr/local/git/current/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/go/bin
```

Where you define `:` as a field separator and you print all the fields on the line.
If you do not mind if there is an empty line at the end you can use an easier command:

```
$ echo $PATH | awk 'BEGIN{RS=":"}1'
/usr/local/git/current/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/go/bin
```

This time you define `:` as a record separator and you print directly each line.

Answer (score -2):

To print out the $PATH variable line for line you can use a for loop in bash. An example that easily achieve this is.

```
for EACH in $PATH; do echo $EACH; done;
```

Comment: It doesn't print paths in newlines.